# Best Practice for Structuring Rest API Request/Response Models

Tags: c#, rest, oop, architecture

I need advice about the best approach for structuring a restful API project's request-response models.

I have base class for all the API Responses:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If I had the following method that only returns the customer `Id` and `Name`, and, **for now**, there are no other fields that need to be returned for customer...

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Customer")]
public Task<IActionResult> GetCustomers()
{
    var result = _customerManager.GetCustomers(ModelState);
    return ReturnResponse(result, ModelState);
}
```

...then my question is: which of the following is a better implementation for the `GetCustomers` method and the `Manager` class?

1 - Use the `BaseResponse` directy to return my data:

```
public List<BaseResponse> GetCustomers(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{
    return new List<BaseResponse>().Add(
        new BaseResponse { id = "1", Name = "Mike" },
        new BaseResponse { id = "2", Name = "Tom" }
    );
}
```

**Or**

2 - Create a new class for `CustomerResponseModel` as the following and use it to return my data—keeping it empty at first—to take into consideration that new fields which *I don't know yet* may be added in the future.

```
public class CustomerResponseModel : BaseResponse
{

}

public List<CustomerResponseModel> GetCustomers(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
{  
    return new List<CustomerResponseModel>().Add(
        new CustomerResponseModel { id = "1", Name = "Mike" },
        new CustomerResponseModel { id = "2", Name = "Tom" }
    );
}
```

I know both approaches have no memory or performance drawbacks, but I need to know what the best practice is for this case.

There is only one known drawback for the second approach: it will affect the project size on the server side if I apply it for all project entities used for the same case and it is very common as there will be too many empty classes in my project that only inherit from `BaseResponse`.

I need your advice about the best approach for my project from a design and structure perspective and would like to know if any other drawbacks for it exist.

Comment: `BaseResponse` doesn't seem to have any purpose.  What's it for?

Comment: It is sharing the common fields between the response data need to be returned .. from bussiness prespective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such situations I think always on the YAGNI ("You Aren't Gonna Need It") and KISS ("Keep it simple, small") principle. So if you don’t know if it will be necessary in the future, don’t do it. It’s reduce the complexity of your programm and increase the maintainability.

Maintainability, because when I am using your class and see that the return type is "BaseResponse", then I know that the response is a simple data transfer object with always the same fields. So I don’t have to explore each inherited class.

Comment: Thanks @RomanE for your answer ... I'm totally agree with this concepts but there is another point of view is to use the second approach to keep the application structure consistence also to enforce non experienced developers to use the inherited class from `BaseResponse`  to add any new fields and avoid them to add new fields to `BaseResponse` direct.

What i need actually is the best practice for this case..